# Benefits of generators that use data previously loaded in Keras fit_generator()

Tags: python, keras, generator

While looking online at code examples of generators to use in  `keras.fit_generator`, some construct generators by loading data progressively from a directory, but some other take as input data that has been already loaded into memory (pseudo code below).
How does in that case a generator help?

https://keras.io/models/sequential/ -> fit_generator -> generator mentions "avoid duplicate data when using multiprocessing" and it might related to the answer. If that is the case, what is a more detailed explanation?

```py
def generator(data, ...):
    ...
    yield ...



input_data = ...

train_gen = generator(input_data, ...)
val_gen = generator(input_data, ...)

...
model.fit_generator(train_gen,
                    ...,
                    validation_data=val_gen)
                              ..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do anything with a generator, including data augmentation, it's all about creativity. You can:

- Perform data augmentation dynanically (every batch gets a different random augmentation, opposed to performing static augmentation)
- Transform a low memory intermediary data into a big memory final data (example: load images from file names)
- etc.

There is no limit for the options. These are two very common cases where a generator would be great.

If you have data and don't want to do anything with it, then there is no need for a generator.